# ¿Cómo es que md5("240610708") == "0e1337" es true?

Tags: php, hash

Tenemos el siguiente bloque de código:

```
<?php
   var_dump(md5("240610708")=="0e1337");
?>
```

Que retorna bool (true), es decir, para PHP es lo mismo el md5 de 240610708 que cualquier cadena que comience por 0e seguido de un número, ¿Cómo ocurre esto?

Comment: Buenas respuestas, las daría como buenas las dos y de hecho las he votado, pero solo puedo aceptar una. Como comentario y ayuda adicional, diré que se me ocurrió la pregunta al ver el post http://www.hackplayers.com/2018/03/hashes-magicos-en-php-type-jugling.html?m=1

Comment: Yo pondria como aceptada la de Ernesto ya que explica más cómo es la conversión de String a Int

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Al usar el operador `==`para comparar cadenas en `PHP`puedes obtener resultados inesperados. Este operador convierte las cadenas a números y posteriormente hace la comparación.

[Dicha conversión la hace según estos criterios](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Si el string empieza con un dato numérico válido, éste será el valor empleado. De lo contrario, el valor será 0 (cero). Un dato numérico válido es un signo opcional, seguido de uno o más dígitos (opcionalmente puede contener un punto decimal), seguido de un exponente opcional. El exponente es una 'e' o 'E' seguida de uno o más dígitos.

Es decir, el resultado de la operación `md5(...)` empieza por `0e...`y lo comparas con la cadena `0e...`al hacer la conversión númerica ambas cadenas se convierten en el número `0`que al comparalo son iguales y por lo tanto `true`.

Para evitar hay que utilizar el operador `===`:

```
<?php
   var_dump(md5("240610708")==="0e1337");
?>
```

Answer (score 13):

Lo que sucede es que cuando comparas con `==` y tratas con números en strings o la comparación es entre un número y un string, intenta convertir a número primero, y luego hace la comparación:

```
md5("240610708") = "0e462097431906509019562988736854"
```

Y ese String resultante convertido a int seria `0`.

Cuando conviertes el otro elemento de la comparación, `0e1337`, es `0` también, ergo el resultado es `true`.

Si usas `===` el resultado sería `false`.

[Ejemplo online](https://www.ideone.com/mKBzto)